# Duplicate elements in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am all of a sudden getting duplicate elements in my listview. When I onClick action on the list items, everything comes back to normal. I also checked my adapter, I am not adding multiple items in the ArrayList. What can possibly be wrong here.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookingresponse_row, null);
            final CabbieViewHolder viewHolder = new CabbieViewHolder();
            viewHolder.call = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.callCab);
            viewHolder.call.setOnClickListener(this);
            viewHolder.driverName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driverName);
            //SIMILAR CODE FOR MORE DATA ITEMs

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        // Setting all values in listview
        String temp = latestAcceptedCabbieName.get(position);
        ((CabbieViewHolder) (convertView.getTag())).driverName.setText(temp);
        ((CabbieViewHolder) (convertView.getTag())).inDetailsDriverName.setText(temp);

        //SIMIAR CODE for other data items
        // Smoothen out the list
        new AsyncTask<Object, Void, Float>() {
            CabbieViewHolder cabbieViewHolder;

            @Override
            protected Float doInBackground(Object... params) {
                float cabDistanceFromCustomer = -1.0f;
                cabbieViewHolder = (CabbieViewHolder) params[0];
                if (cabbieViewHolder.distanceFromCustomer == -1.0f) {
                    int position = (int) ((Integer) params[1]).intValue();
                    cabbieViewHolder.distanceFromCustomer = cabDistanceFromCustomer = God
                            .getGeoDistance(Double.valueOf(latestAcceptedCabbieSourceGPSX
                                    .get(position)), Double
                                    .valueOf(latestAcceptedCabbieSourceGPSY.get(position)),
                                    Double.valueOf(customerSourceLat / 1E6), Double
                                            .valueOf(customerSourceLng / 1E6));
                } else
                    cabDistanceFromCustomer = cabbieViewHolder.distanceFromCustomer;
                return cabDistanceFromCustomer;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Float result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (customerSourceLat != 0 && customerSourceLng != 0) {
                    String temp;
                    if (result != 0) {
                        temp = "Current Location @ Approx "
                                + String.format("%.1f", result / 1000) + " km";
                        cabbieViewHolder.cabDistance.setText(temp);
                        cabbieViewHolder.inDetailsCabDistance.setText(temp);
                    } else {
                        cabbieViewHolder.cabDistance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        cabbieViewHolder.inDetailsCabDistance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else {
                    cabbieViewHolder.cabDistance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cabbieViewHolder.inDetailsCabDistance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }.execute((CabbieViewHolder) convertView.getTag(), new Integer(position));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are loading the content in an asynchronous task.  If the task has not completed yet you will see the old content.

Try putting a "loading data" indicator in the view so you know the data is stale in an else block that executes when convertView is not null.

Comment: Also you may need to invalidate the ListView to force a repaint after you have populated the view in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having a race condition there. You're returning `convertView` before it's initialized by the `AsyncTask`. Keep in mind that `return convertView` might well be executed before `doInBackground` is called.

I suggest you either load all view data in one `AsyncTask` or wait until `postExecute` is called to return the `convertView`. Or simply don't use `AsyncTask` if the workload is not very slow.